# How to make certain posts not appear on the main page, but instead only a newly created category(in the menu section)

Tags: posts, menus

my question pertains to the wordpress.org platform. Recently i created a new category for my posts(called reviews) and added it as a part of the menu. Basically i wanted to send all the book reviews in to this new menu addition, rather than posting it along with all other posts in the main page. What happened is the posts with book reviews are now appearing in the main page, as well as in the newly created Reviews menu bar. I want them to appear book reviews only in the new menu bar. Can You help?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude posts in the "Reviews" category from the main feed using the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook and some [`WP_Query` knowledge](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_home() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'category__not_in', 4 );
    }
});
```

Here I've assumed the ID of the category is `4`, you'll need to [find out what yours is](https://www.mhthemes.com/support/how-to-find-wordpress-category-id/).